# Override attr_readonly in data migration to populate a new read only field on existing records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have added a UUID field to an existing model. I want it to be read only so it cannot be changed.

Model:

```
class Token < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_readonly :uuid
  before_create :set_uuid, on: create

  def set_uuid
    self.uuid = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(8)
  end
end
```

However I want to populate exiting records with UUIDs. I cannot do this through a default value because they are not generated dynamically.

I could write a custom validator in the model, but this seems like overkill when I only really want to override the attr_readonly in the data migration.

As it stands my data migration does not change the value for existing values from nil.

Data Migration:

```
class AddUuidToTokens < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    Token.all.each do |token|
    if token.uuid.nil?
      token.uuid = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(8)
      token.save!
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just override the `Token` class itself in the migration:

```
class AddUuidToTokens < ActiveRecord::Migration
  class Token < ActiveRecord::Base
  end

  def self.up
    Token.where(uuid: nil).find_each do |token|
      token.update_columns(uuid: SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(8))
    end
  end
end
```

Minor improvement: Load only records without an `uuid` instead of checking all records against `nil?`.